# JTable: show data containing a List

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've a list of Objects called "Profile" and each Profile has a list of Functionality (something that a profile can do) and a list of Users associated with that profile.

I want to show this information in a JTable. First, show the profile with le functionalities followed by the users in that profile. Something like this:

```
------------------------------------
|Profile | Operation1 | Operation 2|
------------------------------------
P1       |     X      |            | <- users1 in P1 can do only Operation1
 --user1 |            |            | 
 --user2 |            |            | 
P2       |     X      |     X      |
 --user2 |            |            | 
 --user3 |            |            |
 --user4 |            |            | 
------------------------------------
```

So first I've implemented a smarter getRowCount() method and then a getValueAt method that prints in JTable a profile and under its row all the users associated with it.
Things seem to work but when a click on a row, the JTable is completed modified even if isCellEditor() return always false and the method setValueAt(..) is not implemented (the row is changed with the last Profile added into the JTable).
Could anyone tell me why this happens? I thought that, maybe, the method getValueAt(...) is recalled everytime a row is clicked and this gets trouble with my data structure!
And, next, there is a way to tell to JTable that the columns contain Boolean only is the row is related to a Profile? Thank you in advance

Next, the code:
JFrame:

```
import it.Profile.Operation;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class JTableTest extends JFrame {

List<Profile> list_profiles = new LinkedList<Profile>();
List<User> list_users = new LinkedList<User>();

public JTableTest() {
    super();

    Profile admin = new Profile("P1");
    admin.addOp(Operation.OPERATION1);
    admin.addOp(Operation.OPERATION2);
    admin.addUser(new User("User 1"));
    list_profiles.add(admin);

    Profile p1 = new Profile("P2");
    p1.addOp(Operation.OPERATION2);
    p1.addUser(new User("User 2"));
    list_profiles.add(p1);

    Profile p2 = new Profile("P3");
    p2.addOp(Operation.OPERATION1);
    p2.addOp(Operation.OPERATION3);
    p2.addUser(new User("User 1"));
    list_profiles.add(p2);

    create_jframe();
}

private void create_jframe() {

    JTable profile_jtable = new JTable(new ProfileTableModel());
    DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) profile_jtable
            .getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
    renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(0);

    this.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(profile_jtable),
            BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jframe = new JTableTest();
    jframe.pack();
    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jframe.setVisible(true);
}

private class ProfileTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    /**
     * 
     */
    int riga = 0;
    private int users_number = 0;
    private Profile profilo = list_profiles.get(riga);
    private boolean show_profile = true;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7525220824319997602L;
    private String[] columns_name = { "User", "OPERATION 1", "OPERATION 2",
            "OPERATION 3" };

    public ProfileTableModel() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columns_name.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        int count = list_profiles.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < list_profiles.size(); i++) {
            count += list_profiles.get(i).getListUsers().size();
        }
        return count;
    }

    /*
     * @Override public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) { if (c == 0) return
     * String.class; return Boolean.class; }
     */

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {

        if (show_profile) {
            if (column == 0)
                return profilo.getName();
            Operation f = null;
            switch (column) {
            case 1:
                f = Operation.OPERATION1;
                break;

            case 2:
                f = Operation.OPERATION2;
                break;

            case 3:
                f = Operation.OPERATION3;
                users_number = profilo.getListUsers().size();
                if (users_number != 0)
                    show_profile = false;
                break;
            }
            return list_profiles.get(riga).getOperations().contains(f);
        } else {

            if (column == 0) {
                users_number--;
                String nome = profilo.getListUsers().get(users_number)
                        .getName();
                if (users_number == 0 && riga < list_profiles.size() - 1) {
                    riga++;
                    profilo = list_profiles.get(riga);
                }
                return "---" + nome;
            }
            if (column == 3)
                show_profile = true;

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int i) {
        return columns_name[i];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        if (row == 0 || row == 1)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

   }
}
```

Profile:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Profile {

public enum Operation {
    OPERATION1, OPERATION2, OPERATION3 
}

private List<Operation> list_operations;
private String name;
private List<User> list_users;

public Profile (String name) {
    this.name=name;
    this.list_operations=new LinkedList<Operation>();
    this.list_users=new LinkedList<User>();
}

public Profile (String name, List<Operation> list_operation) {
    this.name=name;
    this.list_operations=list_operations;
}

public void addOp(Operation new_function) {
    this.list_operations.add(new_function);
}

public void removeOp(Operation op) {
    this.list_operations.remove(op);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public List<Operation> getOperations() {
    return this.list_operations;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name=name;
}

public void addUser(User user) {
    this.list_users.add(user);
}

public List<User> getListUsers() {
    return list_users;
}
}
```

User:
    public class User {

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

private String name;


public User (String name) {
    this.name=name;
}
}
```

Upolad image let you understand my problem:
Before click, when things seem to work

[image]

After click, when my dreams crash :P

[image]

You can see that on click the jTable structure is modified.

**EDIT: getValueAt modified in base of Mr. Eric's tip**

```
@Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        int cpt = 0;
        int profile = 0;
        int user = 0;
        for (Profile p : list_profiles) {
            if (cpt++ == row) {
                if (column == 0)
                    return list_profiles.get(profile).getName();
                Operation f = null;
                switch (column) {
                case 1:
                    f = Operation.OPERATION1;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    f = Operation.OPERATION2;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    f = Operation.OPERATION3;
                    profile++;
                    break;
                }
                return list_profiles.get(profile).getOperations()
                        .contains(f);
            } else {
                String nome;
                for (User u : p.getListUsers()) {
                    if (cpt++ == row) {
                        if (column == 0) {
                            return list_profiles.get(profile)
                                    .getListUsers().get(user).getName();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: I still do not understand what happens when you click, and what you expected. Can you post an MCVE?

Comment: I added two images (before and after the click event) so you can see what happens and my class code if you want to run my example on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from what you are doing in your `getValueAt()` method. Basically you are changing the state of the table model with the fields `riga`, `show_profile`, `profilo` and `users_number`.

You assume that Swing is calling `getValueAt()` always in the right order (1st row, 1st column, then 1st row, 2nd column, and so on). This works the first time, but after you click in the table, maybe Swing needs to call `getValueAt()` again for a particular cell, and this messes completely with your model. **Instead, you should assume that Swing will call `getValueAt()` whenever it feels like it, and in whatever order.**

So you should get rid of these fields, and apply a stateless logic. For instance, to know what to display at a given row, you could go through your list and stop at the right row:

```
int cpt = 0
for(Profile p : list_profiles){
   if(cpt++ == row){
      // return value corresponding to profile      
   }else{
      for(User u: p.getListUsers()){
         if(cpt++ == row)
             // return value corresponding to user     
      }
   }
}
```

> And, next, there is a way to tell to JTable that the columns contain Boolean only is the row is related to a Profile?

I think if you return a `Boolean` instead of a `String` in `getValueAt()`, Swing will properly display it the `JTable`. You also need to override the `getColumnClass()` method and return `String.class` for `column==0` and `Boolean.class` otherwise. (Returning `null` will display an empty cell, as is currently the case)

**Note:** Maybe considerer using a TreeTable for your use-case (that will make your model a little simpler to implement, as your data naturally has a tree structure). SwingX has a [really good implementation](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTreeTable.html).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Sorry but I don't understand the logic in your methos. how does variable cpt understand if a profile or an user must be displayed?

Comment: `cpt` is just a counter you increment until you reach the correct row. If you had only profiles and no users, you would just display `list_profiles.get(row)`. But as you are also displaying users, you need this kind of trick to know what object corresponds to a particular `row`.